# How to add numbers to all lines matching a certain regex?

Tags: regular-expressions, markdown-mode, numbers

I have a Markdown file like this:

```
# Title

## My Theme

Pellentesque dapibus suscipit ligula.

### Mine is yours

Donec posuere augue in quam.

## Your Theme

* Suspendisse potenti.
* Aenean in sem ac leo mollis blandit.

## Their Theme

Donec neque quam, dignissim in, mollis nec, sagittis eu, wisi. Phasellus lacus. Etiam laoreet quam sed arcu.
```

In this file I want to add to all lines starting with "`##` " a number, so that the text looks like

```
## 1. My Theme

Pellentesque dapibus suscipit ligula.

## 2. Your Theme

...

## 3. Their Theme

...
```

How can I do this counting up with an Emacs command? `rectangle-number-lines` can't do it because it counts in *consecutive* lines only.

*PS*: I am looking for a solution inserting the numbers to the markdown source, not a hack which instructs the Markdown renderer  to later produce these numbers in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two go-to options for inserting counters:

1. Keyboard macros.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Keyboard Macro Counter`

2. Regexp replacement.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Regexp Replace`:

```
‘\#’ refers to the count of replacements already made in this command,
as a decimal number.  In the first replacement, ‘\#’ stands for ‘0’;
in the second, for ‘1’; and so on.
```

The counting is zero-based in both cases.  With keyboard macros there
are commands to manipulate the counter value.  With regexp replacement
you can employ lisp code in the replacement like so:

```
\,(1+ \#)
```

(And if you can't remember how to do these things, you can always use
the trivial hack of introducing a temporary dummy match in front of
the first real one before executing the macro or replacement command.)

Comment: I did not know Elisp expressions could be used in the replacement, but it makes total sense to do that in Emacs.  Using the techniques you described, the replace expression I came up with to solve the problem was `## \,(1+ \#). ` .

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot for this. Great to know about the replacement counter!